# Change a form's action dynamically on thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I currently have a select dropdown box which shows one of several input file browsers (each allows only one of ".txt", ".cvs" and so on) according to the selected option. I want to change the form's action depending on the selected option so I can handle each case in a different method on the controller's side.

This example works when not using thymeleaf:

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "option1"){
        $("#form").attr("action", "/processopt1");
    }
});
```

I am trying the following for thymeleaf without success:

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "option1"){
        $("#form").attr("th:action", "@{/processopt1}");
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must enable [script inlining](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart). For Thymeleaf expressions to be evaluated, you must use the commented out double brackets syntax: `/*[[...]]*/`

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var action = /*[[@{/processopt1}]]*/ '/processopt1';
    $("#myselect").change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "option1"){
            $("#form").attr("action", action);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Because the expression is commented out, templating will still work when staticly displaying the page.

When the expression is evaluated, Thymeleaf will automatically remove any code after the expression.

**Data attributes**

Another option would be to use `data` attributes on the items of your select box, which you can also build dynamically with Thymeleaf:

```
<select id="myselect" th:forEach="item : ${items}>
    <option th:attr="data-action=${item.action}">${item.name}</option> 
</select>
```

With this option, you can avoid script inlining when you change your script to the following:

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
    var action = $("#myselect option:selected").data("action");
    $("#form").attr("action", action);
});
```

Comment: I've just tried the first approach and works just as wanted, thanks!